# How to include tbb.so dynamic library in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, tbb

While using the TBB dynamic library the following error occurred and how to use the tbb in Linux and how to solve the following error?

> error : libirml.so.1 file not recognized : file format not recongnized

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you post an example of the code you're using, as well as the complete error?

Comment: did you try `gcc -fPIC`? for example: `gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall a.c`
`gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall b.c`
`gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmystuff.so.1 \
    -o libmystuff.so.1.0.1 a.o b.o -lc`, and them try to put them in makefile

Answer (score 0):

Please start by checking that the file `libirml.so.` is really a shared library using the [ldd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) command:

```
$> ldd libirml.so.1
```

If the file is broken you will have a message like:

> not a dynamic executable

Otherwise (case of a truly shared lib) you will have some info like these:

> libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00002)
>
> /lib/ld-linux-64.so.2 (0x00005)